# Integration of trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, integration

Can anyone explain to me why the below expression:

$$\int\frac{2\cos x}{{(4-4\sin^2x})^{3/2}}\:dx$$

is equal to this:

$$\frac{2}{8}\int\frac{\cos x}{{(1-\sin^2x})^{3/2}}\:dx$$

a) Why the constant $2/8$ outside the integral is not $2/4$?

b) And how do you arrive at?

$$\int\frac{1}{{(4\cos^2x})}\:dx$$

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. $4^{3/2}=8$ And $\frac28=\frac14$

Comment: They just wrote $2/4$ to help the reader see that the $2$ was from the numerator and the $8$ was from the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int\frac{2\cos x}{{(4-4\sin^2x})^{(3/2)}}\:dx$$

$$ \int\frac{2\cos x}{{4^{3/2}(1-\sin^2x})^{(3/2)}}\:dx$$

$$=\frac{2}{8}\int\frac{\cos x}{{(1-\sin^2x})^{(3/2)}}\:dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{\cos x}{{(\cos^2x})^{(3/2)}}\:dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{\cos x}{{(\cos^3x})}\:dx$$

$$\int\frac{1}{{4\cos^2x}}\:dx$$

Comment: Very kind excuse me for this comment. It is very nice $\cos x$ instead of $cos x$.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an absolute value on simplifying $\bigl(\cos^2x\bigr)^{3/2}$?

Comment: @Bernard:  I think there should be an absolute value, unless $\cos x>0$

Comment: thanks very much. my problem is I was not taking into account the power when taking the constant out.

Answer (score 3):

Use that $4^{3/2}=8$ as pointed out in the comments and also
$$(1-\sin^2x)^{3/2}=(\cos^2x)^{3/2}=\cos^3x$$

Comment: It is $|\cos^3x|$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
4^{3/2} = \sqrt 4^3 = 2^3 = 8.
$$